# Why does NSTimer crash outside UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nstimer, forward-declaration

I am trying to make code more readable by rearranging related methods including `NSTimer` which I had previously placed in a `UIViewController`. I now need to relocate these to custom class so they can work independently of the `ViewController`.

But in my attempts to do this, I have introduced a problem with NSTimer that wasn’t there previously even though the code looks correct. A crash happens with the following error log:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

When I try using a breakpoint and stepping through the code Xcode seems to be stuck in a loop on this statement

```
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(nextClock)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

Here is a skinny version of my code. `NSTimer` is in a class called `ConcertController` which has a forward declaration in `PlayViewController.h`

**PlayViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "ConcertController.h"

    @interface PlayViewController : UIViewController

    {    
        ConcertController *concertStateMachine;    
    }

    @end
```

and is called from `viewDidLoad` in `PlayViewController.m`

**PlayViewController.m**

```
    #import "PlayViewController.h"

    @implementation PlayViewController { 

    }

    @synthesize lastEventChangeTime;

    ...
    ...

    - (void)viewDidLoad                                             
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      selectedFamily         = [parent getSelectedFamily];
      selectedPlayerID       = [parent getSelectedPlayerID];

      concertStateMachine    = [[ConcertController alloc] initConcertStateMachine:(int)selectedFamily
                                                                        forPlayer:(int)selectedPlayerID];

      CGRect rect            = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
      float  statusBarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
      screenFrame            = CGRectMake(0,statusBarHeight,rect.size.width,rect.size.height - statusBarHeight);
      self.view              = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: screenFrame];

    }
```

`ConcertController` has a forward declaration in `PlayViewController.h`

**ConcertController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class PlayViewController;

    @interface ConcertController : NSObject
    {
        int        currentState;
        NSUInteger clockCount;
        int        totalMinutes;
        int        totalSeconds;
        …
        …

        NSDate*    lastEventChangeTime;
        NSTimer*   timer;
    }

    - (id)initConcertStateMachine:(int)selectedFamily 
                        forPlayer:(int)selectedPlayerID;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *lastEventChangeTime;

    @end
```

**ConcertController.m**

```
    #import "PlayViewController.h"
    @implementation ConcertController

    @synthesize lastEventChangeTime;

    - (id)initConcertStateMachine:(int)selectedFamily
                        forPlayer:(int)selectedPlayerID
    {    
        [self  findEntryPointsFor:(int)selectedFamily
                        andPlayer:(int)selectedPlayerID];
        [self startClock];

        return self;
    }


    - (void)startClock
    {     
    lastEventChangeTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];

        currentState    =  0; // CLOCK_Init_CurrentState;
        clockCount      = 24; // number of seconds per state
        totalMinutes    =  0  // CLOCK_Init_totalMinutes;
        totalSeconds    =  0; // CLOCK_Init_totalSeconds;

        timer           = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(nextClock)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
    }


    - (void)nextClock                                       
    {    
    lastEventChangeTime = [NSDate date];
    clockCount++;
    [self masterClockReadout];

    if ((clockCount % (int)24) == 0) 
        {
         // [self nextState]; // other (i.e. non-UIView) code goes here
        }
    }
```

---

EDIT #2

initialisation in ConcertController.m has been standardised as recommended.

```
    - (id)initConcertStateMachine:(int)selectedFamily
                forPlayer:(int)selectedPlayerID
    {
        self = [super init];

        if (self) {

            [self findEntryPointsFor:(int)selectedFamily
                   andPlayer:(int)selectedPlayerID];        
            [self startClock];
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

EDIT #1. Here is a log as requested. Note: log will also show some items not found in the posted code examples (removed for the sake of clarity). Greg

```
2017-07-25 17:06:30.809 SatGam2[5476:1809452] FamilySelectViewController loaded
2017-07-25 17:06:34.361 SatGam2[5476:1809452] PlayerIDSelectViewController loaded
2017-07-25 17:06:36.250 SatGam2[5476:1809452] SyncViewController loaded (Family 1 PlayerID 1)
2017-07-25 17:06:38.376 SatGam2[5476:1809452] Initialising MotionListener
2017-07-25 17:06:38.674444+1000 SatGam2[5476:1811506] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (1): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.692 SatGam2[5476:1809452] PlayViewController init called and AudioSession active
2017-07-25 17:06:38.693 SatGam2[5476:1809452] MIDI Event [tuningTransposition: 1 assignedPitches: 1]
2017-07-25 17:06:38.694 SatGam2[5476:1809452] Selected octave is 2
2017-07-25 17:06:38.694 SatGam2[5476:1809452] Dekany : index  MIDI Note Number     Frequency
2017-07-25 17:06:38.694 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          52     63                   662.2421
2017-07-25 17:06:38.695 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          53     64                   708.2311
2017-07-25 17:06:38.695 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          54     65                   772.6157
2017-07-25 17:06:38.695 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          55     66                   809.407
2017-07-25 17:06:38.695 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          56     67                   882.9894
2017-07-25 17:06:38.695 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          57     68                   910.5828
2017-07-25 17:06:38.696 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          58     69                   993.3631
2017-07-25 17:06:38.696 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          59     70                   1030.154
2017-07-25 17:06:38.696 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          60     73                   1158.924
2017-07-25 17:06:38.696 SatGam2[5476:1809452]          61     74                   1214.11
2017-07-25 17:06:38.697 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 
(
    "662.2421",
    "708.2311",
    "772.6157",
    "809.407",
    "882.9894",
    "910.5828",
    "993.3631",
    "1030.154",
    "1158.924",
    "1214.11"
)
2017-07-25 17:06:38.697 SatGam2[5476:1809452] concert sequence for selectedFamily 1 and selectedPlayerID 1
2017-07-25 17:06:38.697 SatGam2[5476:1809452] entryPoints
2017-07-25 17:06:38.697 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  1  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.698 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  2  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.698 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  3  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.698 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  4  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.698 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  5  0 -1  48
2017-07-25 17:06:38.698 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  6  0  0  24
2017-07-25 17:06:38.699 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  7  1  1   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.699 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  8  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.699 SatGam2[5476:1809452]  9  0 -1  48
2017-07-25 17:06:38.699 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 10  0  0  24
2017-07-25 17:06:38.700 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 11  1  1   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.700 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 12  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.700 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 13  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.700 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 14  0 -1  96
2017-07-25 17:06:38.700 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 15  0  0  72
2017-07-25 17:06:38.700 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 16  0  0  48
2017-07-25 17:06:38.701 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 17  0  0  24
2017-07-25 17:06:38.701 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 18  1  1   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.701 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 19  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.701 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 20  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.701 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 21  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.702 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 22  0 -1 144
2017-07-25 17:06:38.702 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 23  0  0 120
2017-07-25 17:06:38.702 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 24  0  0  96
2017-07-25 17:06:38.702 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 25  0  0  72
2017-07-25 17:06:38.702 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 26  0  0  48
2017-07-25 17:06:38.702 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 27  0  0  24
2017-07-25 17:06:38.703 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 28  1  1   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.703 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 29  1  0   0
2017-07-25 17:06:38.703 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 30  0 -1  48
2017-07-25 17:06:38.703 SatGam2[5476:1809452] 31  0  0  24
(lldb) bt
  * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
    frame #0: 0x03144383 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 19
  * frame #1: 0x00081c1c SatGam2`-[ConcertController startClock](self=0x786bb480, _cmd="startClock") at ConcertController.m:46 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00081b87 SatGam2`-[ConcertController initConcertStateMachine:forPlayer:](self=0x786bb480, _cmd="initConcertStateMachine:forPlayer:", selectedFamily=1, selectedPlayerID=1) at ConcertController.m:25 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x00093a16 SatGam2`-[PlayViewController viewDidLoad](self=0x7aa49c00, _cmd="viewDidLoad") at PlayViewController.m:154 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x014e2878 UIKit`-[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 38
    frame #5: 0x014e7201 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1434
    frame #6: 0x014e776c UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 29
    frame #7: 0x00085c29 SatGam2`-[MultiviewViewController displayView:](self=<unavailable>, _cmd="displayView:", intNewView=<unavailable>) at MultiviewViewController.m:45 [opt]
    frame #8: 0x000825ed SatGam2`-[MultiviewAppDelegate displayView:](self=0x793a1360, _cmd="displayView:", intNewView=4) at    MultiviewAppDelegate.m:17 [opt]
    frame #9: 0x0008828e SatGam2`-[SyncViewController fromSyncButton:](self=<unavailable>, _cmd="fromSyncButton:", button=0x7b67deb0) at SyncViewController.m:65 [opt]
    frame #10: 0x03146220 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 63
    frame #11: 0x0131fca0 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 91
    frame #12: 0x0131fc3a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 41
    frame #13: 0x014c7f67 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 64
    frame #14: 0x014c82d1 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 469
    frame #15: 0x014c7207 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 666
    frame #16: 0x01396526 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 3066
    frame #17: 0x01397dea UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4445
    frame #18: 0x0133e1b0 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 363
    frame #19: 0x01bbac2f UIKit`__dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2973
    frame #20: 0x01bb20ff UIKit`__handleEventQueue + 1255
    frame #21: 0x01bb3663 UIKit`__handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 66
    frame #22: 0x0360aa5f    CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    frame #23: 0x035f01c4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 500
    frame #24: 0x035ef69c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1084
    frame #25: 0x035eefd4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 372
    frame #26: 0x035eee4b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #27: 0x0516aa7a GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 71
    frame #28: 0x0516a95f GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 80
    frame #29: 0x0131dbc9 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 148
    frame #30: 0x00080f74 SatGam2`main(argc=1, argv=0xbff82818) at main.m:12 [opt]
    frame #31: 0x05f0e779 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    (lldb)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Why you do not send release to lastEventChangeTime variable in -(void)startClock method before assign the new value?

Comment: If you do not use ARC, you have many problems with memory management.

Comment: Do you use ARC? You should really use properties instead of ivars.

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC

Comment: You should stop the timer on deallocation of the view controller, and if the view controller discards the concert controller.

Comment: I think problem in an other place. The code looks good. May be a crash log (with a stack trace) can help to you find a problem. Sometimes a debugger of XCode stops on strange places.

Comment: Indeed, running the analyzer and / or Instruments would be helpful.

Comment: running analyzer, there are no memory leaks, there are also two dead stores but they're related to an earlier UIView. Other than that it's pretty clean. But I haven't got a clue how I would go about using instruments. Suggestions welcome at this stage.

Comment: I tried your code of "ConcertController" and it's working fine. I didn't found any crash. You share your log with us.

Comment: Chaaruu, I edited the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if that's it, but I think you should not call `startClock` in your initializer. That init method is in general not following the correct structure of a decent initializer, i.e.

```
- (instancetype)init... {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // initialize properties (and ivars in your case)
    }
    return self;
}
```

I think the problem is that you're scheduling the timer, which holds a reference to `self`, i.e. the `ConcertController` instance before the initializer is done, i.e. there isn't really a `self` yet. Especially because you never called `super`'s initializer either (unless you do that in that `findEntryPointsFor:andPlayer:` method, which totally voids any convention).
It probably works already if you just call `startClock` later (for example from the view controller), but I would *really* recommend fixing your `init` to suffice the conventions. Don't forget that especially under ARC that is more than just coding aesthetics, ARC also relies on certain things to properly deduce what to retain and release etc.

Besides that, the fact you're defining ivars directly is a bit fishy. I guess that comes from the migration from MRC? I'd recommend to use properties here as well (which is not a really performance loss, as many people seem to wrongly believe). The only thing to keep in mind then is that in the *initializer*, you access them with `_ivarName` (i.e. underscore notation) and rely on the getters and setters elsewhere (i.e. usually dot syntax, except some edge cases where you need to avoid some key-value observing stuff, but as I see it from here you don't even have that). This is really the cleaner and safer way to go, especially for when you want to replace the timer and all that. If you're concerned about keeping the class's public interface clean, use a class extension, that's still better than ivars.

Comment: Gero, I corrected the initialisation as suggested. The last sentence says what I need to do to fix the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your declaration of ConcertController is not good.

Try this for your PlayVC header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ConcertController.h"

@interface PlayViewController : UIViewController

{    
     // remove this line.
}

@property (nonatomic, strong)  ConcertController *concertStateMachine;  

@end
```

If it is not a property, the object normally will be freely released by iOS when memory is needed. In your ConcertController you also should change   NSTimer*   timer; to be property too. Give a try.

Comment: @Gero and GeneCode, thanks, I tried both your suggestions but the fault does not change. Gero, see EDIT #2. Both of you recognise a limitation in my approach that I have not yet been able to see. I think I’d like to try properties instead of ivars. Would it be possible for you to point me to a simple example of this that uses NSTimer ?

Answer (score -2):

If you are not using ARC,

then Change this to:

```
lastEventChangeTime = [NSDate date];
```

Try to add a retain to it

```
lastEventChangeTime = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

And when you finished your lastEventChangeTime, set

```
lastEventChangeTime = nil;
```

Comment: It is unclear if the OP uses MRC. When you retain a variable you should release it. Instead of `[[NSDate date] retain]` you should prefer `[[NSDate alloc] init]` or the shorter `[NSDate new]` to avoid the useless use of ARP. (EDIT: He uses ARC.)

Comment: because I'm using ARC retain is not available

Comment: @macmoonshine, are you sure what a compiler does not optimise this?

Comment: In MRC(!) the compiler optimize nothing. In ARC you could simply use the original statement.

Comment: A sole `lastEventChangeTime = nil;` leads to a leak in MRC. You must release the reference first. But the OP uses ARC (see comments).

Comment: i don't know the reason for the down vote but personally I would keep this answer under consideration. I was not using ARC when I wrote the original version of the changed code. The change to ARC happened recently but wasn't mentioned as it didn't seem like an issue.